# Correct foreigen key approach in jpa Or data saving basic approach

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0

This question of mine is subjective

i am getting a list of objects from a third site.
now i want to save that data in database.
suppose the data is List. This response is to a query that i fired to  that site .
now i want to save two things
1) query name
2) the response(List)  (answer)
the myobject can have lot of answers corresponding to  my query. now i want to save all these answers separately  so that each answer  can be fetched independently.

now i have this DB approach

one table for query  and query id

second table which will consist of query id and query answer. (which will be foreigen key in first table

My question is am i following right approach?

initially i thought of saving the whole list in database but as per my knowledge we can not save list in database directly although in jpa implementation 2.0 we can save list in db  (correct me if i am wrong)

please guide me with my current approach or of there is any better approach

i am using JPA 2.0 eclipselink.

Regards
Anil Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your object model?

You can use OneToMany or ManyToMany to store a collection of Entity objects.

If you have a List or List you can store this using an ElementCollection.
But you may be better off creating an Answer or AnswerReference Entity.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: thanx james for your attention,actually iam using  one to many relationship. but just want to confirm with you guys. there is one more problem i am facing error while  using ddl statement in table generation. my secondary table (i.e   in one to many relation ship my table which should contain many(fields) is not getting generated .although i have used ddl generation statement. i will share the code